# Not able to load application.conf from cron job in play framework 2.4

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have created a cron job that start during application restart but when i tried to create db connection i am geeting null pointer exception. I am able to create and use db from other module using same configuration.

Below is my Application.conf

```
db.abc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.abc.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false"
db.abc.username=root
db.abc.password=""
db.abc.autocommit=false
db.abc.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
```

And code that tried to access db is

```
public class SchduleJob extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(JobOne.class)
        .to(JobOneImpl.class)
        .asEagerSingleton();
    }    }

@ImplementedBy(JobOneImpl.class)
public interface JobOne {}

@Singleton
public class JobOneImpl implements JobOne {
    final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("name");
    final ActorRef alertActor = actorSystem.actorOf(AlertActor.props);

    public JobOneImpl() {
        scheduleJobs();
    }

    private Cancellable scheduleJobs() {
        return actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay 0 milliseconds
                Duration.create(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES),     //Frequency 30 minutes
                alertActor,
                "alert",
                actorSystem.dispatcher(),
                null
                );
    }
}

public class AlertActor  extends UntypedActor{

public static Props props = Props.create(AlertActor.class);
final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("name");
final ActorRef messageActor = actorSystem.actorOf(MessageActor.props());

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if(message != null && message instanceof String) {
        RequestDAO requestDAO = new RequestDAO();
        try {
            List<DBRow> rows = requestDAO.getAllRow();  
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class RequestDAO {
public List<DBRow> getAllRow() throws Exception {
        List<DBRow> rows = new ArrayList<DBRow>();
        Connection connection = null;    
        try {
            connection = DB.getDataSource("abc").getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
} catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            } else {
                System.out.println("in else***********");
            }
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
        }
        return schools; 
    }
```

When i am calling method getAllRow() of RequestDAO class it's throwing

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:235)
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:235)
    at play.utils.InlineCache.fresh(InlineCache.scala:69)
    at play.utils.InlineCache.apply(InlineCache.scala:55)
    at play.api.db.DB$.db(DB.scala:22)
    at play.api.db.DB$.getDataSource(DB.scala:41)
    at play.api.db.DB.getDataSource(DB.scala)
    at play.db.DB.getDataSource(DB.java:33)
```

But same code is working without cron job. What should i do to remove this error

Comment: I think is related to the execution order. Your cron has been created as an eager singleton and sends "alert" immediately to the alert actor. When you get the exception, the app has not finished creating the injector for the DB. Please try to set the initial delay to 1000 milliseconds, just to see if then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Play uses the [Typesafe config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) for configuration.

I suspect your current working directory from the cron script isn't set, so it's probably not finding your `application.conf` (`application.properties`) file.

However, Config is nice in that it allows you to specify where to look for the file, either by its base name (to choose among `.conf` | `.properties` | `.json` extensions) or the filename including the extension on the java command line:

- To specify the base name, use `-Dconfig.resource=/path/to/application`
- To specify the full name, use `-Dconfig.file=/path/to/application.properties`

Comment: when i tried to run application using activator  -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf run still i am geeting same error. And during play startup i got following log                                                application - Creating Pool for datasource 'abc'
[info] - play.api.db.DefaultDBApi - Database [srp] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useSSL=false

Comment: That means play already created DB connection. If yes then why it's throwing exception from cron job

Comment: If it's not config related, then I did notice another problem in the first code listing: `AlertActor` creates a new ActorSystem, which seems wrong. The ActorSystem is created in `JobOneImpl`, and from any actor can be reached using `context().system()`. Perhaps that's related to the issue?

Comment: Still i am getting same exception after commenting two line inside  `AlertActor final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("name");
final ActorRef messageActor = actorSystem.actorOf(MessageActor.props());`